# Python code debugging fails when file contains import matplotlib statement (VS Code and Pycharm)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm writing a program for research/analysis using python in VS Code. The debugger crashes whenever it reaches an `import matplotlib` statement. Running the code normally without the debugger works fine.

The most basic program I've tried to replicate this problem is

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib

print('Hello World!')
```

This crashes the debugger at line 2. Breakpoint placed before this line work as normal. I haven't changed anything in the config file for the debugger.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this issue or what to fix?

Comment: I think you have not installed matplotlib

Comment: My actual work code runs normally, along with matplotlib plots. It's only when debugging that it errors out at the import matplotlib line. I originally had matplotlib 2.2 installed. I updated it to 3.0.0 to see if it helps, but the debugging issue persists.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint into the `__init__.py` of matplotlib and continue step by step from there to see where it crashes exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Klaus. I'm not sure I know how to set the breakpoint in the `__init__.py` of matplotlib. When I try to 'Step Into' the matplotlib statement, the debugger still crashes without opening the matplotlib file. I couldn't find an obvious solution on Google search to set the breakpoint in the matplotlib. How should I do this?

Comment: Open the file manually and placed a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks. I located the file at `AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py` opened it and and set multiple breakpoints within it, however none of them were hit. The debugger again failed as soon as it reached the import matplotlib line in the original program.

Comment: What's the actual crash output? And do note that PyCharm and VS Code use the same underlying debugger.

Comment: @Brett In VS code, it didn't generate any crash output at all. In Pycharm, running the code would show 'Matplotlib failed' message multiple times. 

I read someone who'd posted something similar and was recommended to roll back the matplotlib version to 2.1.2. I did a clean re-install of Anaconda + VS code with an older installer, which seems to have fixed the issue for now.  Thank you guys for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing exactly the same issue. 
It's only recently (I think since the August release of the Python extension, though I'm not sure)
When I comment out "Import matplotlib" the debugger works fine.

**EDIT**: 
I've just found a workaround for this:

Put a breakpoint on the import matplotlib line

then, click step over (not continue) in the debug toolbox.

After this debugging works fine (you can click continue to get to your next breakpoint)

Comment: Isn't that the same as commenting out `import matplotlib`? :)

Comment: No, step over execute the import matplotlib command, so you can still use it.